# vba runtime error 424 object required - string indexing

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I looked at the other links and none seem to help me out. I am writing code for a program that will count all the commas in a phrase. I am not new to programming but I am new to VBA.

```
Sub examp()

Dim s As String

Dim i, my_c As Integer

i = 0

s = ",jkqk;j,oiheqfjnq;ef,jwhef;ur,jwefun;jwkbnf," '<-------arbitrary, however, when I tried to make it input from a textbox it gave me error 424 as well, so I just defined it as random chars with commas

While i < Len(s)

    For i = 0 To Len(s) - 1

    j = s.Chars(i)  <----------------------------------Error occurs here
        If j = "," Then
            my_c = my_c + 1
    End If
    Next i
Wend

Count.Text = "my_c"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

1. change `j = s.Chars(i)` to `j = Mid(s,i,1)`
2. in line `Dim i, my_c As Integer` only `my_c` is `Integer`, but `i`
   is `Variant`. You should declare each variable explicitly: `Dim i As Integer, my_c As Integer`
3. not sure what exactly is your `Count` (maybe textbox), but use
   `Count.Text = my_c` without quotes.
4. also I can't undersand why do you use two loops? `While i < Len(s)`
   is odd.
5. `For i = 0 To Len(s) - 1` should be `For i = 1 To Len(s)`

If you want to count commas, there is more efficient way:

```
Dim s As String
Dim my_c As Integer
s = ",jkqk;j,oiheqfjnq;ef,jwhef;ur,jwefun;jwkbnf,"
my_c = Len(s) - Len(Replace(s, ",", ""))
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try this:

```
Sub test()

Dim s As String
Dim c
Dim my_c As Long

s = ",jkqk;j,oiheqfjnq;ef,jwhef;ur,jwefun;jwkbnf,"
c = Split(s, ",")
my_c = UBound(c)
Debug.Print my_c

End Sub
```